# TFX results in TypeCheckError: Output type hint violation at WriteStatsOutput[train]: expected <class 'apache_beam.pvalue.PDone'>, got <class 'str'>

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, apache-beam, tfx

I tried running the tutorial provided in tfx documentation and I am facing a problem with the path to metadata.

I have described the query in detail in this issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/issues/4993.

The documentation I am using is https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/tfx/penguin_tfdv.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the root cause was using a version of Apache Beam that was incompatible with the version of TFX. When using TFX, you may want to pin your Beam version.

Answer (score 0):

This error should be fixed when using latest version of TFX. I ran the same code in colab with TFX verison `1.9.0`, Tensorflow version `2.9.0` and I haven't got any `TypeCheckError`. Please find the working [gist here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/sanatmpa1/ac76a547d1e15db7d218eec113422fe2/penguin_tfdv.ipynb). Thank you!